# how to prove that the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2$ is passing through point $(0,0)$

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry

How can one prove that the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2$ is passing through point $(0,0)$?

I know that if i put: $x=y=0$,  i will get: $(0-a)^2+(0-b)=a^2+b^2=a^2+b^2$

But that's not a proof but checking.

Thanks.

Comment: For me it's a correct proof

Comment: That is a proof. Checking that an equation is true, using the laws of algebra, is a perfectly valid proof.

Comment: You showed that the point $(0,0)$ lies on the circle, so what more do you need?

Comment: The equation holds for $x=y=0$. So the circle is passing through $(0,0)$

Comment: it is a perfect proof

Comment: isn't it a tautological proof? they want to show it so of course it will be true if i'll use what i need to prove..

Comment: "Showing" and "proving", in this context, are the same thing. How else do you prove something, other than by showing that it is true?

Comment: @don The question is "does (x,y)=(0,0) satisfy this equation?" - all you need to do is to check that it does - which you've done.

Comment: And, by the way, you did **not** use what you need to prove. So there is nothing "tautological" or "circular" in your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$(x-x_M)^2+(y-y_M)^2=r^2$$ describes the circle (to be more specific the circle line) with center $(x_M,y_M)$ and radius $r$. This means, that every point $(a,b)$ that lies on the circle line fulfills this equation. Also the other way around, every point $(a,b)$ that fulfills this equation must lie on the circle line. In your situation you have $x_M=a,y_M=b$ and $r^2=a^2+b^2$.

So if you have to show that the circle passes through a specific point, it is indeed enough to just pluck the point in the given equation and see if everything turns out well.

Comment: What matters here is that every point whose coordinates satisfy the equation belongs to the circle. Not the other way.

Comment: @Siméon, as a point belongs to the circle iff it satisfies the equation, it should not matter. ;) But I do aggree with you, I'll put it in later, when I'm not on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2$ represents a circle with a radius $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ & center at the point $(a, b)$.

Now, the distance of the given point $(0, 0)$ from the center $(a, b)$ of the circle $$=\sqrt{(a-0)^2+(b-0)^2}$$ $$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$  $$=\text{radius of circle}$$
But the above result is true only when the point $(0, 0)$ lies on the circumference of the circle i.e. the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2$ passes through the point $(0, 0)$

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this illustrates the difference between "showing" or "proving" as opposed to "verifying".

Just plugging in the values $x=0$ and $y=0$ and getting LHS=RHS is **verifying** the result.

To show or prove it you could show that the distance from the origin to the centre is the same as the radius, which is straightforward enough.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted. Would anyone care to explain?